# Experimental parser based on a Tree of (String, Set a)

Tags: parsing, haskell

The parser function is immutable and is completely based on the forest of strings with associated properties (String,Set a).

Changing the forest changes the behavior of the parser.

The use of Data.Tree allows very compact data storage and fast access to the string properties, especially in the case of large databases.

The set of properties of a string allows grammatical ambiguity.

The parser can easily and correctly distinguish between "in", "in addition of" and "in front of" in each context.

Specialized functions allow you to combine parsers (forest of (string, properties)) in various ways.

Any comments, criticisms or suggestions are welcome.

```
module TreeParser
    ( GrammarClass (..)
    , StringPr
    , TreePr
    , ForestPr
    , addStringPrsToForestPr
    , deleteStringFromTreePr
    , deleteStringFromForestPr
    , deleteStringPrsFromForestPr
    , deleteStringPrsFromTreePr
    , differenceForestPr
    , forestPrToList
    , fromListToForestPr
    , fromStringPrToTreePr
    , intersectionForestPr
    , parseForestPr
    , prettyParsed
    , prettyStringPrs
    , propertiesInForestPr
    , propertiesInTreePr
    , showForestPr
    , unionForestPr)
    where

-- Examples at the bottom.

import Data.Tree
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as S
import Data.List (intercalate)  -- only for pretty print.

type StringPr a = (String, Set a)
type TreePr a = Tree (Char,Set a)
type ForestPr a =  [TreePr a]

-- -------------------- Insertion --------------------

addStringPrsToForestPr :: (Foldable t, Ord a) => t (StringPr a) -> ForestPr a -> ForestPr a
addStringPrsToForestPr strprs frst = foldr go frst strprs
    where
    go :: Ord a => StringPr a -> ForestPr a -> ForestPr a
    go ([],_) fr = fr
    go strpr [] = [fromStringPrToTreePr strpr]
    go strpr@([x],sa) fr@(tr@(Node (y,sb) sub) : trs)
      | x == y = Node (y,S.union sa sb) sub : trs
      | x < y = fromStringPrToTreePr strpr : fr
      | otherwise = tr : go strpr trs
    go (xs@(x:rest),sa) fr@(tr@(Node (y,sb) sub) : trs)
      | x == y = Node (y,sb) (go (rest,sa) sub) : trs
      | x < y = fromStringPrToTreePr (xs,sa) : fr
      | otherwise = tr :  go (xs,sa) trs

fromStringPrToTreePr :: Ord a => StringPr a -> TreePr a
fromStringPrToTreePr ([],_) = error "Empty Tree"
fromStringPrToTreePr ([x],sa) = Node (x,sa) []
fromStringPrToTreePr (x:xs,sa) =  Node (x,S.empty) [fromStringPrToTreePr (xs,sa)]

-- -------------------- Deletion --------------------

deleteStringPrsFromTreePr :: Ord a => StringPr a -> TreePr a -> TreePr a
deleteStringPrsFromTreePr ([],_) tr = tr
deleteStringPrsFromTreePr ([x],sp1) tr@(Node (y,sp2) subfrst)
  | x == y = Node (y, sp2 S.\\ sp1) subfrst
  | otherwise = tr
deleteStringPrsFromTreePr (x:xs,sp1) tr@(Node (y,sp2) subfrst)
  | x == y = Node (y,sp2) $ deleteStringPrsFromForestPr (xs,sp1) subfrst
  | otherwise = tr

deleteStringPrsFromForestPr :: Ord a => StringPr a -> ForestPr a -> ForestPr a
deleteStringPrsFromForestPr _ [] = []
deleteStringPrsFromForestPr strprs fr = map (deleteStringPrsFromTreePr strprs) fr

-----

deleteStringFromTreePr :: String -> TreePr a -> Maybe (TreePr a)
deleteStringFromTreePr [] tr = Just tr
deleteStringFromTreePr [x] tr@(Node (y,_) [])
  | x == y = Nothing
  | otherwise = Just tr
deleteStringFromTreePr [x] tr@(Node (y,_) subfrst)
  | x == y = Just $ Node (y,S.empty) subfrst
  | otherwise = Just tr
deleteStringFromTreePr _ tr@(Node (_,_) []) = Just tr
deleteStringFromTreePr (x:xs) tr@(Node (y,sp) subfrst)
  | x == y = let subfrstd = deleteStringFromForestPr xs subfrst
             in if null subfrstd
                then Nothing
                else Just (Node (y,sp) subfrstd)
  | otherwise = Just tr

deleteStringFromForestPr :: String -> ForestPr a -> ForestPr a
deleteStringFromForestPr [] fr = fr
deleteStringFromForestPr _  [] = []
deleteStringFromForestPr xs (tr:rest) =
    case deleteStringFromTreePr xs tr of
        Nothing  -> rest
        Just tr' -> tr' : deleteStringFromForestPr xs rest

-- -------------------- Query --------------------

propertiesInTreePr :: String -> Tree (Char, Set a) -> Set a
propertiesInTreePr [] _ = S.empty
propertiesInTreePr [x] (Node (y,sp) _)
  | x == y = sp
  | otherwise = S.empty
propertiesInTreePr (x:xs) (Node (y,_) fr)
  | x == y = propertiesInForestPr xs fr
  | otherwise = S.empty

propertiesInForestPr :: String -> [Tree (Char, Set a)] -> Set a
propertiesInForestPr _ [] = S.empty
propertiesInForestPr [] _ = S.empty
propertiesInForestPr [x] ((Node (y,sp) _) : trs)
  | x == y = sp
  | otherwise = propertiesInForestPr [x] trs
propertiesInForestPr xs@(x:rest) ((Node (y,_) subfr) : trs)
  | x == y = propertiesInForestPr rest subfr
  | otherwise = propertiesInForestPr xs trs

-- -------------------- Conversion --------------------

fromListToForestPr :: Ord a => [(String, [a])] -> ForestPr a
fromListToForestPr xs = addStringPrsToForestPr (map (fmap S.fromList) xs) []

forestPrToList :: [Tree (Char, Set a)] -> [(String, [a])]
forestPrToList fr = goF fr [] []
    where
    goF [] _ acc = acc
    goF frst invprfx acc = concatMap (\tr -> goT tr invprfx acc) frst

    goT (Node (x,sp) []) invprfx acc = (reverse (x : invprfx),S.toList sp) : acc
    goT (Node (x,sp) subfrst) invprfx acc
      | S.null sp = goF subfrst (x : invprfx) acc
      | otherwise = let invprfx' = (x : invprfx)
                      in goF subfrst invprfx' ((reverse invprfx',S.toList sp) : acc)

-- -------------------- Combine --------------------

-- !!! FORESTS MUST BE IN ASCENDING ORDER !!!
-- Precondition not tested by: unionForestPr, intersectionForestPr, differenceForestPr.

unionForestPr :: Ord a => ForestPr a -> ForestPr a -> ForestPr a
unionForestPr [] fr = fr
unionForestPr fr [] = fr
unionForestPr fr1@(tr1@(Node (x,sp1) subfrst1) : trs1) fr2@(tr2@(Node (y,sp2) subfrst2) : trs2)
  | x < y  = tr1 : unionForestPr trs1 fr2
  | x == y = Node (x,S.union sp1 sp2) (unionForestPr subfrst1 subfrst2) : unionForestPr trs1 trs2
  | otherwise = tr2 : unionForestPr fr1 trs2

intersectionForestPr :: Ord a => ForestPr a -> ForestPr a -> ForestPr a
intersectionForestPr [] _ = []
intersectionForestPr _ [] = []
intersectionForestPr  fr1@((Node (x,sp1) subfrst1) : trs1) fr2@((Node (y,sp2) subfrst2) : trs2)
  | x < y  = intersectionForestPr trs1 fr2
  | x == y = 
        let spi = S.intersection sp1 sp2
            subfrsti =  intersectionForestPr subfrst1 subfrst2
        in if null subfrsti && S.null spi
           then intersectionForestPr trs1 trs2
           else Node (x, spi) subfrsti : intersectionForestPr trs1 trs2
  | otherwise = intersectionForestPr fr1 trs2

differenceForestPr :: Ord a => ForestPr a -> ForestPr a -> ForestPr a
differenceForestPr fr [] = fr
differenceForestPr [] _ = []
differenceForestPr fr1@(tr1@(Node (x,sp1) subfrst1) : trs1) fr2@((Node (y,sp2) subfrst2) : trs2)
  | x < y  = tr1 : differenceForestPr trs1 fr2
  | x == y && sp1 == sp2 =
        let subfrstd = differenceForestPr subfrst1 subfrst2
        in if null subfrstd
           then differenceForestPr trs1 trs2
           else Node (x,S.difference sp1 sp2) subfrstd : differenceForestPr trs1 trs2
  | x == y && sp1 /= sp2 = Node (x,S.difference sp1 sp2) (differenceForestPr subfrst1 subfrst2)
                                    : differenceForestPr trs1 trs2
  | otherwise = differenceForestPr fr1 trs2

-- =========== Parser ===========

parseForestPr :: Ord b => String -> ForestPr b -> ([StringPr b], String)
parseForestPr xs [] = ([],xs)
parseForestPr xs fr = pForestPr xs fr []

pForestPr ::  Ord b => String -> ForestPr b -> [StringPr b] -> ([StringPr b], String)
pForestPr xs fr stringPrAcc = case goF (dropWhile  (==' ') xs) fr [] of
    (Nothing,_)    -> (reverse stringPrAcc,xs)
    (Just ok,rest) -> pForestPr rest fr (ok : stringPrAcc)
    where
    goF :: Ord b => String -> ForestPr b -> String -> (Maybe (StringPr b), String)
    goF [] _ invacc = (Nothing, reverse invacc)
    goF ys [] invacc = (Nothing, reverse invacc <> ys)
    goF ys (tr:trs) invacc = case goT ys tr invacc of
        (Nothing, _) -> goF ys trs invacc
        ok            -> ok

    goT :: Ord b => String -> TreePr b -> String -> (Maybe (StringPr b), String)
    goT [] _ invacc = (Nothing, reverse invacc)
    goT (' ':' ':ys) tr invacc = goT (' ':ys) tr invacc
    goT [x] (Node (y,sp) _) invacc
        | x == y && not (S.null sp) = (Just (acc,sp),[])
        | otherwise = (Nothing, acc)
        where
        acc = reverse (x:invacc)
    goT ys@(x:rest) (Node (y,sp) subfrst) invacc
        | x == y = case goF rest subfrst (x:invacc) of
                      (Nothing,acc) -> if S.null sp
                                         then (Nothing,acc <> rest)
                                         else (Just (reverse (x:invacc),sp),rest)
                      result -> result
        | otherwise = (Nothing,reverse (x:invacc) <> ys)

-- ============================== Pretty Print ==============================

prettyParsed :: Show a => ([StringPr a], String) -> IO ()
prettyParsed (strs,refused) = do
    putStr "NOT PARSED: "
    putStrLn refused
    putStrLn ""
    putStrLn "PARSED:"
    mapM_ putStrLn $ prettyStringPrs strs

prettyStringPrs :: Show a => [StringPr a] -> [String]
prettyStringPrs = map (\(str,sp) -> " " <> str <> ": " <> f sp)
    where
    f sp = intercalate ", " . map show $ S.toList sp

showForestPr :: Show a => ForestPr a -> IO ()
showForestPr = putStr . drawForest . map (fmap (show . fmap S.toList))

-- =========== Examples ===========

data GrammarClass = Adjective | Adverb | Article | CommonNoun | Contraction | Digit | EnglishPossessive | Preposition | Pronoun | ProperNoun | Punctuation | Verb
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

l1 :: [(String, [GrammarClass])]
l1 =  [("!",[Punctuation])
      ,(",",[Punctuation])
      ,("?",[Punctuation])
      ,("'s",[Contraction])  -- see l2
      ,(".",[Punctuation])
      ,("...",[Punctuation])
      ,("1",[Digit])
      ,("7",[Digit])
      ,("8",[Digit])
      ,("9",[Digit])
      ,("England",[ProperNoun])
      ,("He",[Pronoun])
      ,("I",[Pronoun])
      ,("It's",[Verb])
      ,("John",[ProperNoun])
      ,("Red",[Adjective])  -- see l2
      ]

l2 :: [(String, [GrammarClass])]
l2 = [("'s",[EnglishPossessive])  -- see l1
      ,("Red",[ProperNoun])  -- see l1
      ,("apples",[CommonNoun])
      ,("color",[CommonNoun])
      ,("contest",[CommonNoun,Verb])
      ,("favorite",[Adjective,CommonNoun])
      ,("friend",[CommonNoun])
      ,("in",[Preposition])
      ,("in addition to",[Preposition])
      ,("in front of",[Preposition])
      ,("is",[Verb])
      ,("mean",[Verb])
      ,("my",[Pronoun])
      ,("preferred",[Adjective,Verb])
      ,("my",[Pronoun])
      ,("red",[Adjective])
      ,("since",[Adverb])
      ,("teacher",[CommonNoun])
      ,("the",[Article])
      ,("true",[CommonNoun])
      ]

frst1 :: ForestPr GrammarClass
frst1 = fromListToForestPr l1

frst2 :: ForestPr GrammarClass
frst2 = fromListToForestPr l2

frst3 :: ForestPr GrammarClass
frst3 = unionForestPr frst1 frst2

str1 :: String
str1 = concat
    ["Red is my favorite color. "
    ,"Red   is my   favorite friend. "
    ,"Red is the teacher's favorite !"
    ,"Red's favorite color is red ."
    ," Red apples?! "
    ," It's red Red's preferred color. "
    ," He's in front of Red. "
    ," It's true ... "
    ," I mean, in addition to the contest. "
    ," John is in England since 1987! "
    ]

prs :: ([StringPr GrammarClass], String)
prs = parseForestPr str1 frst3

prs' :: IO ()
prs' = prettyParsed prs
```